# Why LimitException is occurred despite using "LIMIT 5000"

Tags: apex

We connect other sever's data and want to delete data(LastModified <= YESTERDAY; total is 52,000).
We want to delete data, LimitException was occurred.
But, SOQL use "LIMIT".

Why LimitException is occurred?
What Should We do?

```
        @RestResource(urlMapping='/RestApiDataDelete')
    global with sharing class RestApiDataDeleteController {

        @HttpGet
    global static String dataDelete(){

        RestRequest req = RestContext.request;
        RestResponse res = Restcontext.response;


        // *****************************************************************

        // data
        while (hasDeleteSample()) {
            List<Sample__c> samples = getDeleteSampleList();
            // Delete
            delete samples;
        }    

        ResultData result = new ResultData();
        result.success = true;
        res.statusCode = 200;

        res.responseBody = Blob.valueOf(JSON.serialize(result));
        return 'Success';
    }

    global class ResultData{
        global Boolean success;
        global ResultError error;
    }

    global class ResultError{
        global String message;
    }

    private static boolean hasDeleteSample() {
        boolean hasData = false;
        List<Sample__c> samples = [Select Id From Sample__c Where LastModifiedDate <= YESTERDAY LIMIT 5000];

        if (samples.size() > 0) {
            hasData = true;
        }
        return hasData;
    }

    private static List<Sample__c> getDeleteSampleList() {
        List<Sample__c> samples = [Select Id From Sample__c Where LastModifiedDate <= YESTERDAY LIMIT 5000];
        return samples;
    }
}
```

Error message

> [ { "errorCode" : "APEX_ERROR", "message" : "System.LimitException:
>   Too many DML rows:
>   10001\n\nClass.RestApiDataDeleteController.dataDelete: line 17,
>   column 1" } ]

Comment: can you check any trigger associated with Sample_c object  and doing DML operations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Governor limits apply to the whole transaction not just a single statement such as:

```
delete samples;
```

So in your case, the third time that statement executes the 10,000 limit is exceeded.

A common solution is to split the work up into multiple transactions by using [Batch Apex](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/asynchronous_apex/async_apex_batch). There you would query all the records in the `start` and make the batch size used per `execute` 10,000 (or smaller if other DML happens as a side effect of the deletes.) But note that this work is done asynchronously, so while your `@HttpGet` can return an OK response, if it is critical to know whether the work has been done or not, you will have to add additional mechanisms.

Perhaps a simpler solution, in this case, is to set up the UI side to make multiple requests while there is still data to delete; that avoids the asynchronous problem.

Comment: The existing solution is based on the [anti-pattern of SOQL and DML in loops](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Best_Practice%3A_Avoid_SOQL_Queries_Inside_FOR_Loops). Applying a Checkmarx scan for coding practice would have highlighted this issue.

Comment: I see. Thank you